# Gnosis Safe Service: Signer is not an owner

Tags: gnosis-safe

The incorrect signer is being recovered by the signature. Where may the error be?

```
const safeTransactionData = await getTxData(tx, safe.getAddress(), web3);

        const safeTransaction = await safe.createTransaction({ safeTransactionData });
        const senderAddress = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];
        const safeTxHash = await safe.getTransactionHash(safeTransaction);
        const signature = await safe.signTransactionHash(safeTxHash);

        const proposeTxProps: ProposeTransactionProps = {
            safeAddress: safe.getAddress(),
            safeTransactionData: safeTransaction.data,
            safeTxHash,
            senderAddress,
            senderSignature: signature.data,
        };

        await safeService?.proposeTransaction(proposeTxProps);
```

[image: error image]

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Signer=0xFB2b4Cc5db4b4cD6e6F0D8E2F64533d3682EbE71 is not an owner or delegate. Current owners=['0x8FB40436758Ea9e1a8317f54293Af74be02faFf0', '0xBda9D28292bab5A4F181C22509BC9B86D46df37D']. Delegates=set()
> at sendRequest (null:95:15)
> at async executeTx (App.tsx:131:3)

Answer (score 1):

This is the function I created to sign the tx manually and it worked:

```
const sign = async (
    signerAddress: string,
    data: SafeTransactionDataPartial,
    chainId: string,
    safeAddress: string,
    web3: Web3
): Promise<string> => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const provider = web3?.currentProvider as any;
        const dataToSign = JSON.stringify({
            types: {
                EIP712Domain: [
                    {
                        type: "uint256",
                        name: "chainId",
                    },
                    {
                        type: "address",
                        name: "verifyingContract",
                    },
                ],
                SafeTx: [
                    { name: "to", type: "address" },
                    { name: "value", type: "uint256" },
                    { name: "data", type: "bytes" },
                    { name: "operation", type: "uint8" },
                    { name: "safeTxGas", type: "uint256" },
                    { name: "baseGas", type: "uint256" },
                    { name: "gasPrice", type: "uint256" },
                    { name: "gasToken", type: "address" },
                    { name: "refundReceiver", type: "address" },
                    { name: "nonce", type: "uint256" },
                ],
            },
            primaryType: "SafeTx",
            domain: {
                chainId,
                verifyingContract: safeAddress,
            },
            message: {
                to: data.to,
                value: data.value || 0,
                data: data.data,
                operation: data.operation || 0,
                safeTxGas: data.safeTxGas || 0,
                baseGas: data.baseGas || 0,
                gasPrice: data.gasPrice || 0,
                gasToken: data.gasToken || "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                refundReceiver: data.refundReceiver || "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
                nonce: data.nonce,
            },
        });

        provider.send(
            {
                jsonrpc: "2.0",
                method: "eth_signTypedData_v4",
                params: [signerAddress, dataToSign],
            },
            (err: any, result: any) => {
                resolve(result.result);
            }
        );
    });
};
```

I created this function to replicate what the package does, but without converting the values to bignumber. I think that is what solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks, this fix will be included in the next release

Comment: Nice, could you also review the issue with the isAddress function? The issue is on this line: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/blob/main/packages/safe-core-sdk-utils/src/eip-3770/index.ts#L32, the isAddress functions gives an error.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `senderAddress`?
I guess you initialized the `safe` instance with an `Web3Adapter` instance. What is the signer address that was passed to it?

Comment: Hi, the signer address is 0xBda9D28292bab5A4F181C22509BC9B86D46df37D, which is an owner of the safe. We managed to solve this by creating our own signing function, since the one provided by the package was not signing the tx correctly. I don't know if it is a bug or if we were doing it wrong, I am posting another answer with the function I made for signing the tx manually.

Comment: Another issue I found was that the SDK utils has a funtion called validateEthereumAddress, which is not working on the browser since the isAddress function from web3-utils is only available in node.js